# Error running bash script empty line $'\r': command not found

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I am calling a bash script through azure devops task in a yaml pipeline.

[image]

[image]

It's a simple bash script to echo some strings but I am getting the following output. It seems like it doesn't like the empty line. I tried adding #!/bin/sh but doesn't seem to help.

```
hello world
/__w/4/s/test.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
this is bash script
```

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings; `bash` sees the carriage return as the last character on the line, unlike the the linefeed.

Comment: Hello, how can i remove or prevent it from happening?